# Limits of indeterminate forms $(-\infty)(0)$

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

Can anybody give me a detailed solution on how
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} -x\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{1+x}}\right) = -1?$$

I understand that separately the limit of each factor is $(-\infty)(0)$ but I could not proceed to getting $-1$. I also tried L'hopitals but I only got as far as

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{-(1-e^{-\frac{1}{1+x}})^{-2}(-e^{-\frac{1}{1+x}})(-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2})} = \frac{-1}{(0)(1)(0)}.$$

Any leads would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: for "reasonable" $a$ we have $\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\frac{a^y-1}{y}=\ln a$

Comment: Justice of the story - take the time of my comment, the time and technique of my answer and compare with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using limit written in comment, we have

$$x\left(e^{-\frac{1}{1+x}}-1\right)=x\cdot\frac{\left(e^{-\frac{1}{1+x}}-1\right)}{-\frac{1}{1+x}}\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{1+x}\right) \sim x\cdot \frac{-1}{1+x}\to -1$$
for $x\to\infty$.

Comment: hey i am still relatively new here im sorry i dont know how to accept two answers

Comment: You can choose the answer you like, and I will be glad if I could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\frac1{1+x}$. Then we have
$$\lim_{u\to 0}\left(\frac1u-1\right)(e^{-u}-1) = \lim_{u\to 0}\frac{e^{-u}-1}u,$$
since $\lim\limits_{u\to 0} (e^{-u}-1)=0$. Now finish by recognizing the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{l}
{\rm\text{Since we knew}}:\displaystyle\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{{e^x} - 1}}{x} = 1\\
 \displaystyle\Rightarrow  - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } x\left( {1 - {e^{ - \frac{1}{{1 + x}}}}} \right) =  - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \left( {\frac{{{e^{ - \frac{1}{{1 + x}}}} - 1}}{{ - \frac{1}{{1 + x}}}}} \right).\left( {\frac{x}{{1 + x}}} \right) =  - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \frac{x}{{1 + x}}\\
 =  \displaystyle - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \frac{1}{{1 + \frac{1}{x}}} =  - 1
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using that as $t\to 0$  we have $ 1+t \le e^t\le 1+t+t^2$ we get

$$-\frac{x}{1+x} \le x\left(e^{-\frac{1}{1+x}}-1\right)\le -\frac{x}{1+x}+\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}$$

which by squeeze theorem leads to $x\left(e^{-\frac{1}{1+x}}-1\right)\to -1$.